# Laravel 8 - Automatically update a form field when certain value is selected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a truck table and a postman table. Both tables have a one to one relationship. One truck has one postman, one postman has one truck.

Inside `postman/create.blade.php` file, there is an HTML form containing `truck_number`, `postman_number`, `postman_name`, and `date_of_operation` to be filled by the user.

the `truck_number` is presented in a dropdown list format, and the list get automatically updated everytime a `truck_number` is created from the truck table. inside the truck table, each of these `truck_number` has its own `date_of_operation`.

Therefore for the `date_of_operation` field inside `postman/create.blade.php` file, I want the value to get updated automatically within that same form when the user selects a particular `truck_number` associated with it.

Is it possible to do this in laravel without involving any form of ajax or json? How can I implement it correctly?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get the value until you have sent a request to server.You can use livewire, A fullstack framework associated with laravel. You can easily do the stuffs you are willing to do. Here is Documentation:
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart

Comment: I see.. so when I use livewire, do I need to integrate it with my entire application or I can just use it for this specific purpose only?

Comment: No you should not change your whole project. Install livewire, if you need to send request without loading the page, create a livewire component for the page. That's it. All the stuffs you can find in the docs.

Comment: I see.. I guess I'll look into it further. thank you so much!